# and/but/because

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I'm writing a short paragraph about a short-term downside of taking risks. I'm not sure which linking word to use. Should I use "and", "but" or "because"?

> Take, for example, adults who receive financial support from their parents **but/and** are psychologically controlled by them. If they stop relying on their parents in the exchange for the freedom to go after their dreams, they may face the short-term downside of losing the comfort their parents' money provides.

vs

> Take, for example, adults who are psychologically controlled by their parents **because** they still receive financial support from them. If they stop relying on their parents in the exchange for the freedom to go after their dreams, they may face the short-term downside of losing the comfort their parents' money provides.

Comment: That depends on your intended meaning! Are you saying that receiving financial support is the _cause_ of being 'psychologically controlled', or just that both things are happening?

Comment: Got it. I'll use "because". Thanks.

Comment: I thought it more. I think "recieve financial support" is more important than "being psychologically controlled" because the main point of this example is about taking the risk of getting off your parents' financial support. I want to make "receiving financial support" important. Does "and therefore" work? Take, for example, adults who still receive financial support from their parents AND THEREFORE are psychologically controlled by them...

Comment: You can say that if you think it's true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The words, "and", "but", and "because" are acting as three different types of conjunction. Wikipedia goes into some detail [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_(grammar)) but in summary:

- **"and"** is a **cumulative coordinating** conjunction, used to join **non-contrasting** items
- **"but"** is an **adversative coordinating** conjunction, used to join **contrasting** items
- **"because"** is a **subordinating** conjunction, used to join **cause** and **effect**

So in fact they all could work in your examples, but which is appropriate depends on exactly what you are trying to say.

If you merely want to mention both psychological control and the receipt of money, without implying any kind of connection, then use "and":

> Take, for example, adults who receive financial support from their parents **and** are psychologically controlled by them.

If you want to suggest that the psychological control (as something negative) stands in contrast with -- or *despite* -- the giving of money (as something positive) then use "but":

> Take, for example, adults who receive financial support from their parents **but** are psychologically controlled by them.

And if you want to suggest a causal connection -- i.e. that the psychological control is actually a result of the provision of money -- then use "because" (and rearrange, as you did):

> Take, for example, adults who are psychologically controlled by their parents **because** they still receive financial support from them.

Given the meaning of the text as a whole, I'd say that "and" is not what you want; "but" could work; however, "because" is best since it implies the strong causal connection that is consistent with the rest of the text.

Finally, you added "and therefore" as another option. I'd say that is the same in meaning as "because", but it means you don't have to reorder the sentence. As a result, does it change the emphasis, putting more weight on the receipt of money than on the psychological control? I guess; maybe? But if it does, the effect is minimal. So I'd say your best choice is still "because" (with the reordering) or your new "and therefore" (without).

Comment: Thanks very much. I think "receiving financial support" is more important than "being psychologically controlled" because the main point of this example is about taking the risk of getting off your parents' financial support. Does putting "receive financial support" in a because-clause make it less important?

Comment: I've added some commentary on that aspect,  but the more I look at your originals the less I think they convey your view that financial support is more important than the control. As you have written them, the most important part of each example is neither the financial support nor the psychological control, but rather is the combination of the two, and in particular the fact that the relation between them is a causal one. Isn't that the whole point of your text; the unfortunate (for the adult children) fact that the financial support comes at a price, and that not paying it is risky?

Comment: Thank you very much. I was struggling because I wanted to put "receiving financial support" in a main clause. Now I understand.